# python write umlauts into file

Tags: python, file, diacritics

i have the following output, which i want to write into a file:

```
l  = ["Bücher", "Hefte, "Mappen"]
```

i do it like:

```
f = codecs.open("testfile.txt", "a", stdout_encoding)
f.write(l)
f.close()
```

in my Textfile i want to see: ["Bücher", "Hefte, "Mappen"] instead of B\xc3\xbccher

Is there any way to do so without looping over the list and decode each item ? Like to give the `write()` function any parameter?

Many thanks

Comment: What's `stdout_encoding`?

Comment: sorry its utf-8

Answer (score 8):

First, make sure you use **unicode** strings: add the "u" prefix to strings:

```
l  = [u"Bücher", u"Hefte", u"Mappen"]
```

Then you can write or append to a file:

I recommend you to use the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module which is Python 2/3 compatible.

```
with io.open("testfile.txt", mode="a", encoding="UTF8") as fd:
    for line in l:
        fd.write(line + "\n")
```

To read your text file in one piece:

```
with io.open("testfile.txt", mode="r", encoding="UTF8") as fd:
    content = fd.read()
```

The result *content* is an Unicode string.

If you decode this string using UTF8 encoding, you'll get *bytes* string like this:

```
b"B\xc3\xbccher"
```

**Edit** using `writelines`.

The method `writelines()` writes a sequence of strings to the file. The sequence can be any iterable object producing strings, typically a list of strings. There is no return value.

```
# add new lines
lines = [line + "\n" for line in l]

with io.open("testfile.txt", mode="a", encoding="UTF8") as fd:
    fd.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thank you. In a case if i should have an output which contains more then one list i need to encode the items in lists seperately. I have no opportunity to do it in one step for ALL output without knowing which list could contain umlauts and which does not? I was looking for a solution which allows me to write output in file without seperately looping over the list and encode strings seperately.

Comment: It's not clear what you really want to do. Encoding (or decoding) is only required when you write (or read) to a file. Because text files are bytes streams: the internal representation is always an array of bytes. The classic usage is to use UTF8 encoding for that.

Comment: i want to write informations to a .txt file and i have the problem that some strings are correctly shown in the textfile like Bücher and other strings, which are inside a list are shown like B\xc3\xbcer.

Comment: If you "write" a Python list directly to a file, Python use the `repr` function which performs a ASCII encoding with backslash escaping. You need to write line by line as I suggested you. You can also use **writelines** but you need to add a délimiter like a newline. See my edit.